# how to open a new tab in Jessie Light terminal (CTL+SHIFT+T has no effect)?

Tags: jessie-lite, lxde, lxterminal

In Jessie light (at least the one I've installed), I can open a terminal window with CTL+ALT+t but how to open a new tab in the terminal (CTL+SHIFT+T has no effect)? The terminal has no menu.
I can't find any relevant `config` file in `~/.config`.

**Edit:**
You can throw tomatoes at me... 
I forgot to clearly state that I had installed LXDE within my Jessie Lite environment (it may have been understood that I had a GUI since I mentioned I could open the terminal with CTL+ALT+t, yet I wasn't clear enough). So I have a terminal console that I can open with `lxterm` (from a console), but it comes without any menu.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you know where to look but just in case make sure you have a lxterminal.conf file in an lxterminal directory in your .config folder by checking the output of:

```
ls -al ~/.config/lxterminal
```

if that command throws an error saying no such directory, create it with:

```
mkdir ~/.config/lxterminal
```

If you do have the directory but it is empty create the lxterminal.conf with:

```
nano ~/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
```

If the file exists it should look like the one copied below.  Check the hotkey section at the bottom and change the "hidemenubar=true" to "hidemenubar=false".

If nano opens and the file is empty you can copy the text below into the file, save with CTRL-o and exit with CTRL+x.

```
[general]
fontname=Monospace 10
selchars=-A-Za-z0-9,./?%&#:_
scrollback=1000
bgcolor=#000000000000
bgalpha=65535
fgcolor=#aaaaaaaaaaaa
disallowbold=false
cursorblinks=false
cursorunderline=false
audiblebell=false
tabpos=top
hidescrollbar=false
hidemenubar=false
hideclosebutton=false
hidepointer=false
disablef10=false
disablealt=false

[shortcut]
new_window_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>N
new_tab_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>T
close_tab_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>W
close_window_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>Q
copy_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>C
paste_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>V
name_tab_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>I
previous_tab_accel=<CTRL>Page_Up
next_tab_accel=<CTRL>Page_Down
move_tab_left_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>Page_Up
move_tab_right_accel=<CTRL><SHIFT>Page_Down
```

after the file is saved and you have exited nano, close the terminal.  When you open it up again, you should see the menu and your hotkey combos should work again.

if it still doesn't work, try removing lxterminal and reinstalling it.

Comment: `lxterminal` requires a GUI - which is not present in the light distributions.

Comment: sorry... i missed that it was jesse lite.  in addition to tmux, the virtual terminals are still available using CTRL+ALT+F1...F12.